# Sumar columna en java

Tags: java

estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio donde el usuario debe meter el número de columnas y el carácter que quiere que aparezca. Estoy hecho un poco de lío a la hora de hacerlo. Os dejo el enunciado:

Realiza un programa utilizando bucles que muestre  la siguiente figura por pantalla, preguntando previamente al usuario cuántas filas desea mostrar y qué carácter desea utilizar (por ejemplo un *). Debes realizar control de excepciones.

Código:

```
public class ejercicio3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    Scanner teclado;
    int Ncolumnas;
    String caracter;


    System.out.print("Introduce cuantas filas deseas mostrar: ");
            teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            Ncolumnas = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Introduce un caracter: ");
            teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            caracter = teclado.next();

            for(int i=1;i>Ncolumnas; i++){
                i++;
            if (Ncolumnas>0){

            System.out.print("Introduce un caracter: " + (caracter + Ncolumnas));
            }else{

            System.out.print("Error ");
            }
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error, no has introducido un carácter");
    }

    }

}
```

Cuando hago esto no me aparece el resultado, por que obviamente, hay algo que estoy haciendo mal.

PD: Novato a la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Luego a primera vista puedes ver el error :

```
for (int i = 1; i > Ncolumnas; i++) { // inicias i=1
  i++;  // aquí ya i = 2
  if (Ncolumnas > 0) { // nunca vas a entrar
```

Un ejemplo para iterar por Ncolumnas es:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Ncolumnas; i++) {
   System.out.println(i); // code
}
```

En este ejemplo has ejecutado la linea comentada por "code" Ncolumnas veces